# Increase Oblivion menu mouse speed

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Howe do I increase Oblivion's menu mouse speed? INI hacks are preferred although I'm open to any mods as a solution.

> Yes, the age old how-to-bloody-increase-mouse-sens-in-menus-because-the-ingame-slider-only-affects-gameplay question. Google shows plenty people having the same issue but no solution, nor could I find a mod to fix the issue. -F4c2a, [Nexus](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/301711-the-mouse-sensitivity-game-menu-vs-game/)

---

> Nah, I figured out what it was. The problem is that I can't properly fix it. Basically, I need to get my graphic's card to not render any frames ahead. But I can't, since it makes my drivers not work. -EternalSpark, [apolyton.net](http://apolyton.net/showthread.php/176301-Oblivion-Mouse-Sensitivity-in-the-menus)

For my AMD HD 7700 video card, 'frames rendered' is not an option. Also, [others have reported](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1997294) this as having no effect. (The link is basically my question and a 3yo tumbleweed on the Steam Forums.)

Desktop resolution has no effect.
In-game resolution set to very low *unacceptably* alleviates this problem.

I'm hoping to avoid deciding on a (resolution) compromise between mouse maneuverability and acceptable graphics.

Comment: What resolution are you using? I play at 1920 x 1080 and haven't noted cursor movement speed as unusual, actually appears to match my desktop mouse movement. I have Oblivion Script Extender and unofficial patches installed. If the game is running at above 60fps, [you should](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_IV:_Oblivion#Video_settings) [cap frame rate](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Glossary:Frame_rate_(FPS)#Frame_rate_capping) to 60fps in any case ("physics issues above 60fps).

Comment: 1680x1050 - but this problem doesn't crop up anymore for me since buying a new cpu and using a 3rd party installer with all the bells and whistles already loaded.